# How does the Amazon Web Services Marketplace handle application upgrades?

Tags: amazon-web-services

If I publish an app in the amazon web services marketplace, and later want to update the software.  What are the best practices in making the new AMI, and instructions to give to end users to make that as painless as possible?

Assume there is a mysql DB and some user uploaded fiels on the instance.

Answer (score 0):

[According to the Marketplace Help Documentation:](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/help/200940380)

> **Updating an AMI**
>
> ***Publishing a new Version of your AMI***
>
> If you wish to publish a new version or an upgrade of your software,
>   you should submit the new AMI to the AWS Marketplace Team. When the
>   new version has been published, **AWS Marketplace will notify your
>   existing users that the new AMI is available and provide them with
>   your release notes and upgrade instructions.**

Comment: I know I can supply release notes and upgrade instructions. I'm looking for best practices I should do to make those upgrades painless.